# How to alter drop data before drop in extjs4.1?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

This is a rewording to my previous question ([How to set an extjs grid record phantom to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724129/how-to-set-an-extjs-grid-record-phantom-to-true)), which for some reason didnot get any attention.

How can I alter dropped data inside a function triggered on 'beforedrop' function? Is this a bug in ExtJS? I've exhausted all solutions.

Example:

```
listeners: {
  beforedrop: function(node, data) {
      console.log('before:'+data.records[0].phantom);
      data.records[0].phantom = true;
      console.log('set:'+data.records[0].phantom);
  },
  drop: function(node, data) {
      console.log('confirm:'+data.records[0].phantom);
  }
```

prints:

```
before:false
set:true
confirm:false
```

Instead of

```
before:false
set:true
confirm:true
```

Comment: Can use setup a small demo maybe on jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com - A place where people can edit the code and play with it.

Comment: It's sometimes hard to get attention with Extjs question that is, at least with my observations, because it is mostly companies concerned about the server side of programming who chooses to use it. People who isn't usually listening to the JavaScript/Extjs question stream

Comment: Yeah, I gues you are right. JSFiddle maynot replicate my issue well because I get my data from the server, faking it may cause a different outcome.

Comment: The core issue though is this: data is dragged correctly and dropped correctly, but the store at the target is not recogizing the new data because `phantom` flag is set to `false`. How can I change that?

Comment: I'm not sure about if you should use `phantom` or what you should do. Maybe you could try using `.setDirty()` instead, see docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-setDirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code from [handleNodeDrop](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.ViewDropZone-method-handleNodeDrop) which is called after the `beforeDrop` event is fired but before the `drop` event.

```
if (data.copy) {
    records = data.records;
    data.records = [];
    for (i = 0, len = records.length; i < len; i++) {
        data.records.push(records[i].copy());
    }
}
```

The implementation of `copy` on `Model` doesn't copy the `phantom` property on the record. If the record has an id and it is copied it will have `phantom` set to false in the copy.

Is `data.copy` set to true? If so, this is almost certainly what is happening. One way you can fix this is to override the copy method on Model to also copy the phantom state. Another way is to override handleNodeDrop to copy over the phantom state after copying the record.

Comment: I overridden the model's `copy` method to the following: `copy: function() {
        var me = this;
        var c = new me.self(me.raw, null, null, Ext.apply({}, me[me.persistenceProperty]));
        c.id = null;
        c.phantom = true;
        return c;
    }`, the store.getNewRecords() now picks up the new records, but the records dont end up being added to the store!?

Comment: @Is7aq If `store.getNewRecords()` returns the records they must be getting added to that store. What do you mean by they don't end up being added to the store? Try changing your override to `copy: function() { var c = this.callParent(arguments); c.phantom = true; return c; }`

Comment: you're right, it's all set now. I was using getTotalCount() on the store to check if the record was there or not, and that's why I didnot see the fix. Thank you for your time!